# Complete online form VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web

I have created a test form [here](https://form.jotformeu.com/91133129129351) and I am trying to fill it out with values I have in an excel file.

My code stops at the line: 'Call ie.Document.getelementbyid("input_11").setAttribute("value", activity)' and it does not copy the data from the first cell, this is how my excel file looks like:

[image]

```
'Sub internet()

Dim ie As Object
Dim activitate As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, j As Integer
i = 1
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row - 1
j = 0

'open page
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://form.jotformeu.com/91133129129351"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

While i < 11
For Each c In Range("2:2")
activity = c.Value
Call ie.Document.getelementbyid("input_11").setAttribute("value", activity)
Next c
Wend


End Sub'
```

I'm trying to get past this code error, thank you for your time!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but I usually don't see this with the CALL keyword.  The pattern I'm used to is targetElement = doc.getElementById(...)  [new line] if(Not targetElement Is Nothing) Then targetElement.Value = "..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somethink like that must be

```
Sub test()

    Dim IeApp As Object
    Dim IeDoc As Object
    Dim ieEL As Object

    Set IeApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IeApp.Visible = True ' make Explorer visible
            IeApp.Navigate "https://form.jotformeu.com/91133129129351"
        Do While IeApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop ' wait for page load
        'Do Until IeApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

        Set IeDoc = IeApp.Document ' set loaded content to variable
            For Each ieEL In IeDoc.getElementsByTagName("input") ' loop all inputs
                If InStr(ieEL.Name, "activitate") > 0 Then ' check if inputs name has activate name
                    i = i + 1 ' increment for pick up valaues from sheet
                    ieEL.Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value ' set value from sheets 2 row and i column
                End If
            Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it does work, can you explain me a bit what was wrong or explain me some rows of your code in the second part so I can learn. Thank you very much!! Appreciate it,

Comment: problem that you loop range and dont change elements id